# getting values from multiple forms

Tags: php, html, forms

i want to get values into the database from multiple forms

here are the forms

```
 <td width="191"><div align="left"><strong>First Name</strong></div></td>
          <td width="336" colspan="2"><form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="Register.php">
            <label for="textfield2"></label>
            <input type="text" size="50px" name="fname" id="fname" />
            </form></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="left"><strong>Last Name</strong></div></td>
          <td colspan="2"><form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="Register.php">
            <label for="textfield3"></label>
            <input type="text" size="50px" name="lname" id="lname" />
            </form></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="left"><strong>User Name</strong></div></td>
          <td colspan="2"><form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="Register.php">
            <label for="textfield4"></label>
            <input type="text" size="50px" name="uname" id="uname" />
            </form></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="left"><strong>Password</strong></div></td>
          <td colspan="2"><form id="form6" name="form6" method="post" action="Register.php">
            <label for="textfield5"></label>
            <input type="password" size="50px" name="password" id="password" />
            </form></td>
          </tr>
```

PHP:

```
  <?php 

    ;
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

                    if(!$con)
                    {
                        die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
                    }

                    mysql_select_db("toolmate",$con);

                            $sql ="

                    INSERT INTO  `toolmate`.`supply` (
                    `email` ,
                    `fname` ,'lname',
                    `username:`
                    )
                    VALUES ('".$_POST["email"]."',  '".$_POST["fname"]."', '".$_POST["lname"]."' ,'".$_POST["uname"]."')";

                            mysql_query($sql, $con); //Execute the query
                    mysql_close($con);  //Close the connection
?>
```

but I am getting an error saying post["email"]post["fname "]not found

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: To point you in the right direction, you can not submit multiple forms at once.  You can submit one form at a time.  You probably want one form with multiple inputs, not multiple forms with one input each.

Comment: Also, please remove all that extra white space and fix the tabbing. A tidier and well presented question is more likely to get a response.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 different

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post"
```

in the code, so each of them will have separate `action` page, in this line :

```
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="Register.php">
```

the action page is mentioned as `register.php` but rest of the forms are just blank.

To solve it, remove all `<form>` tags and place `inputs` into 1 `<form>` having `register.php`

---

and just on side note :

**you seriously need to update your HTML and PHP knowledge before asking such basic questions!!**